# wkhtmltopdf: 100mm aren't 100mm

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

Given the following file `test.html`:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <table style="width:100mm;border:1px solid">
        <tr><td>test</td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

converted with

```
wkhtmltopdf ./test.html ./test.pdf
```

produces a pdf which, when printed, contains a box that is `100mm` wide in **no case**. Depending on the os (Win/Mac/Linux) and the parameter `--disable-smart-shrinkink` I get different results. Some longer than 100mm, some shorter. But no one exactly 100mm long.

Is there any chance to get an os independent and exact result?

Comment: Looking at the PDF's internals could shed light on what's happening (it's text, y'know).

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: Seems logical, but does not work. a) there are streams within the pdf containing unreadable chars and b) the pdf script is cryptic (at least for me).

Comment: Windows assumes a monitor resolution of 96ppi, but your monitor may well not have that resolution. If you calculate how long your 100mm line should appear using the actual resolution, is it correct? You can tell Windows the actual ppi: [Get a better view in Windows 7 by adjusting DPI scaling](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/get-a-better-view-in-windows-7-by-adjusting-dpi-scaling/), but a lot of things may end up being blurry.